# google analytics api and daily users from a time period

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using google anayltics php client from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

I want to get daily unique visitors(users) like below

```
   Date    - visitors
2018-01-11 - 1000 
2018-01-10 - 983
2018-01-09 - 1023
```

I only know how to get the total.

```
$profileId = 'xxxxxxx';
$startDate = "2012-01-01";    

$results = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profileId,$startDate,'today','ga:users');
```

Would i have to loop through everyday from the beginning of 2012 or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the `ga:date` parameter

```
$optParams['dimensions']  = 'ga:date';
$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       $startDate,
       'today',
       'ga:users',$optParams);
```